# How to use Git properly for same codebase

Tags: git, github, project

I am fairly new to Git / GitHub but I've already set up a few (~30) **private** repos.

My project - which is my *master* repo - looks like this:

- shared codebase ([S]CSS, [T]JS)
- indiv styles ([S]CSS)

The shared codebase is partially used in the indiv styles (variables). And looks like this:
[image: My *master* codebase]

My **question** is:

Does it make sense to work with branches, even they aren't merged with the master? What other possibilities do I have? All resources I read where about to merge the branch into master after solving things.

The project I'm working on will grow to about 150 repos.

Currently I am working like that:

- Checkout *master*
- change remote src to new repo
- install dependencies
- check in under new repo

My *main* target is to minimize the effort when the codebase changes.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: Well, it depends TBH. Maybe have a read up on [git flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html). If it's a private repo and your the only one working on it the cases for using branching is possibly a bit thin but without a lot more info, who knows

Comment: 150 repos sounds pretty massive, even larger than many big companies would have.  This leads me to believe that maybe you are using repos incorrectly.  A given repo should ideally correspond to a single code base.  Within that repo, there can be many different branches, each of which corresponds to some point in the development process.  If this does not jive with your current understanding, then you should hit a good tutorial on Git.

Comment: Thank you for your response @TimBiegeleisen, so you would suggest to use branches instead of repos, right? Even if they never get merged into master branch?

Comment: Please read the documentation until you understand well the difference between a repo and a branch.